# Python web app form generates excel or pdf after submit

Tags: python, html, django

So I have this questions and answers form in a web application, most questions are input based, there are some that are checkbox, list or a date, but most are text/number input. I want that after the submit button it generates a link to download or downloads directly after the file is written. I cannot seem to find this answer anywhere and I'll gladly appreciate some help. Code is written as Django form with python.

home2.html

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %} {% block title%} Home2 {%endblock title%}

{%block Formulario%}
<form id="form">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="fecha" id="label-fecha"> Fecha </label>
      <input type="date" id="date" placeholder="Ingrese fecha" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Cargo Actual" id="label-Cargo Actual"
        >Su cargo actual</label
      >
      <input type="text" id="cargo" placeholder="Ingrese Cargo" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Lugar y Fecha de Nacimiento" id="label-F/L nac"
        >Lugar y fecha de Nacimiento</label
      >
      <input type="text" id="FLNac" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Discapacidad" id="label-Disc">Grado de discapacidad</label>
      <input type"text" id='discapacidad' placeholder='En caso de tener
      discapacidad ingrese el grado,caso contrario deje vacio '>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="edad" id="label-edad"> Edad: </label>
      <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="Ingrese edad" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="tipo_sangre" id="label-tipo_sangre">Tipo de Sangre:</label>
      <input type
       ="text"
        id="tipo_sangre"
        placeholder="Ingrese tipo de sangre"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Estatura" id="label-Estatura"> Estatura: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="Estatura"
        placeholder="Ingrese su estatura"
        step=".01"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Direccion_Domicilio" id="label-Direccion"
        >Direccion Domicilio Actual</label
      >
      <input type="text" id="Domicilio" placeholder="Ingrese su Direccion" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Manzana" id="label-Manzana"> Manzana: </label>
      <input type="text" id="Manzana" placeholder="Ingrese Manzana" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Villa" id="label-Villa"> Villa: </label>
      <input type="text" id="villa" placeholder="Ingrese villa" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Parroquia" id="label-Parroquia"> Parroquia </label>
      <input type"text" id='Parroquia' placeholder="Ingrese Parroquia">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="telefonoD" id="label-telefonoD"> Telefono Domicilio </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="tel_domicilio"
        placeholder="Ingrese telefono domicilio"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="telefonoC" id="label-telefonoC"> Telefono Celular </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="tel_personal"
        placeholder="Ingrese telefono celular"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="telefonoF" id="label-telefonoF">Telefono Familiar </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="tel_familiar"
        placeholder="Ingrese telefono familiar"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Cedula" id="label-cedula"> Cedula de Identidad: </label>
      <input type="number" id ="cedula" placeholder="Ingrese su cedula">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="Estado_Civil" id="label-Estado_Civil">
        Cual es su Estado Civil actual
      </label>
      <select name="Estado_Civil" id="Estado_Civil">
        <option value="Soltero(a)">Soltero</option>
        <option value="Union_Libre">Union Libre</option>
        <option value="Casado">Casado</option>
        <option value="Viudo">Viudo</option>
        <option value="Divorciado">Divorciado</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <h2> Informacion del Conyuge o Esposo </h2>
    <small> En el caso de no tener Conyuge o Esposo/a dejar vacio <small>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for='NCE' id="label-NCE"> Nombre Completo del conyuge o Esposo/a</label>
          <input type='text' id='NCE' placeholder="Ingrese el nombre respectivo">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for='Direccion_DomicilioNCE' id="label-Direccion_DomicilioNCE"> Direccion Domiciliaria: </label>
          <input type="text" id='DDNCE' placeholder="Ingrese Direccion Domiciliaria">
      </div>
      <div class ='form-control'>
          <label for='Num_C/E ' id='label-NumC/E'> Telefono:</label>
          <input type="number" id="Num_C/E" placeholder="Ingrese telefono">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for='ced_C/E' id="label-ced_C/E"> Cedula de Identidad:</label>
          <input type="number" id="ced_C/E" placeholder="Ingrese Cedula">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="Fecha_NacC/E" id="label-NacC/E"> Fecha de Nacimiento: </label>
          <input type="date" id="Fecha_NacC/E" placeholder="Ingrese fecha de Nacimiento">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="Lug_TrabajoC/E" id="label-Lug_TrabajoC/E"> Lugar y Direccion de Trabajo: </label>
          <input type="text" id="Lug_TrabajoC/E" placeholder="Ingrese Lugar y Direccion del trabajo">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="tel_trabajoC/E" id="label-tel_trabajoC/E"> Telefono del Trabajo </label>
          <input type="text" id="tel_trabajoC/E" placeholder='Ingrese telefono'>
      </div>
      <h2>Informacion de los Hijos</h2>
          <font size='-0'> En caso de no tener hijos dejar vacio </font>
              <h4> Hijo 1: </h4>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='kid1' id='label-kid1'> Nombre hijo/a: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='kid1' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='F/LK1' id='label-F/LK1'> Fecha y Lugar de nacimiento: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='K1FL' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class= "form-control">
                  <label for="Edadk1" id='label-Edadk1'> Edad: </label >
                  <input type='text' id="AgeK1" placeholder='Ingrese edad'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='Ced/Ciud' id='label-Ced/Ciud'> Cedula/Ciudadania: </label>
                  <input type='text' id= 'Ced/CiudK1' placeholder='Ingrese Cedula'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for="Direccion" id="label-Direccion_Hijos"> Direccion Domiciliaria </label>
                  <input type='text' id='direccionHijo1'placeholder='Ingrese Direccion'>
              </div>
              <h4> Hijo 2: </h4>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='kid2' id='label-kid2'> Nombre hijo/a: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='kid2' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='F/LK2' id='label-F/LK2'> Fecha y Lugar de nacimiento: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='K2FL' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class= "form-control">
                  <label for="Edadk2" id='label-Edadk2'> Edad: </label >
                  <input type='text' id="AgeK2" placeholder='Ingrese edad'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='Ced/Ciud' id='label-Ced/Ciud'> Cedula/Ciudadania: </label>
                  <input type='text' id= 'Ced/CiudK2' placeholder='Ingrese Cedula'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for="Direccion" id="label-Direccion_Hijos"> Direccion Domiciliaria </label>
                  <input type='text' id='direccionHijo2'placeholder='Ingrese Direccion'>
              </div>
              <h4> Hijo 3: </h4>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='kid3' id='label-kid3'> Nombre hijo/a: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='kid3' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='F/LK3' id='label-F/LK3'> Fecha y Lugar de nacimiento: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='K3FL' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class= "form-control">
                  <label for="Edadk3" id='label-Edadk3'> Edad: </label >
                  <input type='text' id="AgeK3" placeholder='Ingrese edad'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='Ced/Ciud' id='label-Ced/Ciud'> Cedula/Ciudadania: </label>
                  <input type='text' id= 'Ced/CiudK3' placeholder='Ingrese Cedula'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for="Direccion" id="label-Direccion_Hijos"> Direccion Domiciliaria </label>
                  <input type='text' id='direccionHijo3'placeholder='Ingrese Direccion'>
              </div>
              <h4> Hijo 4: </h4>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='kid4' id='label-kid4'> Nombre hijo/a: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='kid4' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='F/LK4' id='label-F/LK4'> Fecha y Lugar de nacimiento: </label>
                  <input type='text' id='K4FL' placeholder="Nombre del hijo">
              </div>
              <div class= "form-control">
                  <label for="Edadk4" id='label-Edadk4'> Edad: </label >
                  <input type='text' id="AgeK4" placeholder='Ingrese edad'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for='Ced/Ciud' id='label-Ced/Ciud'> Cedula/Ciudadania: </label>
                  <input type='text' id= 'Ced/CiudK4' placeholder='Ingrese Cedula'>
              </div>
              <div class='form-control'>
                  <label for="Direccion" id="label-Direccion_Hijos"> Direccion Domiciliaria </label>
                  <input type='text' id='direccionHijo4'placeholder='Ingrese Direccion'>
              </div>
          <h2> Familiares con Discapacidad </h2>
          <div class='form-control'>
              <label for='inp-1'>
                  <input type='checkbox' name='inp'> Tiene esposo/a con discapacidad </input></label>
              <label for='inp-2'>
                  <input type="checkbox" name='inp'> Tiene hijos/as con discapacidad </input></label>
          </div>

          <h2>Informacion de Familiares </h2>
              <font size='-0'>  "Padres y hermanos" </font> 
              <div  class='form-control'>
                  <label for="ApellidosNom"  id="label-ApellidosNom"> Apellidos Y Nombres </label>
                  <input type="text" id="AyNFam" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres">

                  <input type="text" id="AyNFam2" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres">
                  
                  <input type="text" id="AyNFam3" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres">
              </div>
              <div  class='form-control'>
                  <label for="telefonoFam"  id="label-telefonoFam"> Telefono </label>
                  <input type="text" id="telefonoFam" placeholder="Ingrese Telefono">
                  <input type="text" id="telefonoFam" placeholder="Ingrese Telefono">
                  <input type="text" id="telefonoFam" placeholder="Ingrese Telefono">
              </div>
              <div  class='form-control'>
                  <label for="FNFam"  id="label-FNFam"> Fecha de Nacimiento </label>
                  <input type="text" id="FNFam" placeholder="Ingrese fecha de Nacimiento">
                  <input type="text" id="FNFam" placeholder="Ingrese fecha de Nacimiento">
                  <input type="text" id="FNFam" placeholder="Ingrese fecha de Nacimiento">
              </div>
              <div  class='form-control'>
                  <label for="RelacionFam"  id="label-RelacionFam"> Relacion de Parentesco </label>
                  <input type="text" id="RelacionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Relacion">
                  <input type="text" id="RelacionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Relacion">
                  <input type="text" id="RelacionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Relacion">
              </div>
              <div  class='form-control'>
                  <label for="DireccionFam"  id="label-DireccionFam"> Direccion Domiciliaria</label>
                  <input type="text" id="DireccionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
                  <input type="text" id="DireccionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
                  <input type="text" id="DireccionFam" placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
              </div>
              <div class="form-control">
                  <label for="inp-3"> Trabajan en esta empresa familiares?
                      <input type="checkbox" name="inp">Si </input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="inp">No </input>
                  </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-control">
                  <label for="inp-3"> Trabajan en esta empresa amistades?
                      <input type="checkbox" name="inp">Si </input>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="inp">No </input>
                  </label>
              </div>
      <h2> Referencias Personales  </h2>
      <font size='-0'> Dos diferentes a Familiares </font>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for='Ap_NomRP' id="label-Ap_NomRP"> Nombres y Apellidos</label>
          <input type='text' id='Ap_NomRP' placeholder="Ingrese el nombre ">
          <input type='text' id="Ap_NomRP2" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for='Direccion_DomicilioRP' id="label-Direccion_DomicilioRp"> Direccion Domiciliaria: </label>
          <input type="text" id='DDRP' placeholder="Ingrese Direccion Domiciliaria">
          <input type="text" id='DDRP2' placeholder="Ingrese Direccion Domiciliaria">
      </div>
      <div class ='form-control'>
          <label for='Num_RP ' id='label-NumRP'> Telefono:</label>
          <input type="number" id="Num_RP" placeholder="Ingrese telefono">
          <input type="number" id="Num_RP2" placeholder="Ingrese telefono">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for='OcupacionRP' id='label-OcupacionRP'> Ocupacion </label>
          <input type='text' id="OcupacionRP1" placeholder="Ingrese Ocupacion">
          <input type='text' id="OcupacionRP2" placeholder="Ingrese Ocupacion">
      </div>
      <h2> Experiencia Laboral</h2> 
      <font size='-0'> Si tiene menos de tres años en la empresa </font> 
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="nombreEmpresa" id="label-nombreEmpresa"> Nombre de la Empresa </label>
          <input type='text' id='NombreEmp' placeholder='Ingrese nombre de la empresa'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for='DireccionEmp' id="label-DireccionEmp"> Direccion </label>
          <input type="text" id='DireccionEmp' placeholder="Ingrese Direccion">
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="telefonoEmp" id='label-telefonoEmp'> telefono </label>
          <input type='number' id="telefonoEmp" placeholder="Ingrese telefono">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for='fechaIng' id='label-fechaIng'> Fecha Ingreso: </label>
          <input type='date' id='fechaIng'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="fechaSal" id="label-FechaSal"> Fecha Salida: </label>
          <input type="date" id ='fechaSal'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-control'>
          <label for="SueldoF" id="label-SueldoFin"> Sueldo Final   </label>
          <input type="text" id="SueldoFin" placeholder="Ingrese sueldo">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="UltCargo" id="label-UltCargo"> Ultimo Cargo que desempeno</label>
          <input type="text" id="UltCargo" placeholder="Ingrese su ultimo cargo">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="TiempoServ" id="label-TiempoSev"> Tiempo de Servicio </label>
          <input type="text" id="TiempoServ" placeholder="Ingrese el tiempo que estuvo en la empresa">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="JefeInm" id="label-JefeInm"> Nombre de su Jefe Inmediato</label>
          <input type="text" id="JefeInm" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de su jefe">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="NombreEmpr"id="label-nombreEmpr"> Nombre de la Empresa</label>
          <input type="text" id="NombreEmpr" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de la Empresa">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="DireccionEmp" id="label-DirEmpr"> Direccion: </label>
          <input type="text" id="DireccionEmpr" placeholder="Ingrese direccion">
      </div>
      <h2> Referencias Socioeconomicas </h2>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="inp-4"> Posee Vehiculo <small> Moto o Automovil </small> </label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="inp"> Si </input>
              <input type="checkbox" name="inp"> No </input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="ModeloV" id="label-Modelo"> Modelo </label>
          <input type="text" id="ModeloV" placeholder="Ingrese Modelo">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="MarcaV" id="label-MarcaV"> Marca </label>
          <input type="text" id="MarcaV" placeholder="Ingrese Marca">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="PlacaV" id="label-Placa"> Placa </label>
          <input type="text" id="PlacaV" placeholder="Ingrese Placa">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="AñoV" id="label-Anio"> Año </label>
          <input type="text" id="Anio" placeholder="Ingrese Año">
      </div>  
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="ColorV" id="label-ColorV"> Color </label>
          <input type="text" id="ColorV" placeholder="Ingrese Color">
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <label for="Vivienda" id="label-Vivienda">
            Su vivienda actual es:
          </label>
          <select name="vivienda" id="Vivienda">
            <option value="Propia">Propia</option>
            <option value="Alquilada">Alquilada</option>
            <option value="Familiar">Familiar</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="TipoVivienda" id="label-TipoVivienda">
            Tipo de Vivienda:
          </label>
          <select name="TVivienda" id="TipoVivienda">
            <option value="Hormigon">Hormigon</option>
            <option value="Mixta"> Mixta</option>
            <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
          </select>
          <div class="form-control">
              <label for="inp-4"> Posee Terreno </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="inp"> Si </input>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="inp"> No </input>
          </div>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
  </form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, PasswordResetView, PasswordChangeView
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, UpdateUserForm, UpdateProfileForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'users/home.html')


class RegisterView(View):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'users/register.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # redireccion a home
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(to='/')

        
        return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')

            return redirect(to='login')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data.get('remember_me')

        if not remember_me:
            # Expirar sesion
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

            
            self.request.session.modified = True

        return super(CustomLoginView, self).form_valid(form)


class ResetPasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'users/password_reset.html'
    email_template_name = 'users/password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'users/password_reset_subject'
    success_message = "We've emailed you instructions for setting your password, " \
                      "if an account exists with the email you entered. You should receive them shortly." \
                      " If you don't receive an email, " \
                      "please make sure you've entered the address you registered with, and check your spam folder."
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users-home')


class ChangePasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    success_message = "Successfully Changed Your Password"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users-home')


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile is updated successfully')
            return redirect(to='users-profile')
    else:
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})


@login_required
def home2(request):
    return render(request, "users/Home2.html")

def home2_pdf(request):
    if request.method =="POST": 
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize = letter, bottomup=0)
        textob =c .beginText()
        textob.setTextOrigin(inch,inch)
        textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)  

        lines =[
        
        ]
        for line in lines:
            textob.textLine(line)

        c.drawText(textob)
        c.showPage()
        c.save()
        buf.seek(0)      
        return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename="formulario.pdf")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

from .models import Profile


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                                 required=True,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name',
                                                               'class': 'form-control',
                                                               }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                                required=True,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name',
                                                              'class': 'form-control',
                                                              }))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                             'class': 'form-control',
                                                             }))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email',
                                                           'class': 'form-control',
                                                           }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                                required=True,
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                                  'class': 'form-control',
                                                                  'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                                  'id': 'password',
                                                                  }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                                required=True,
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
                                                                  'class': 'form-control',
                                                                  'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                                  'id': 'password',
                                                                  }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username',
                                                             'class': 'form-control',
                                                             }))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                                 'class': 'form-control',
                                                                 'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                                 'id': 'password',
                                                                 'name': 'password',
                                                                 }))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'remember_me']


class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}))
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'bio']
```

Have created now a button that generates a PDF File but its completely empty, Im still not sure how to fill it with the data from my user input

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Cannot access the form request=="POST" from my html at the moment. Program confuses each of the previous forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view in Django that accepts the POST request from the form.
Then use library like reportLab to generate the pdf file.

After you generated the pdf file you can return it like that:

```py
response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="application/pdf")
response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'

return response
```

Comment: Hello, my access to the form request=="POST" keeps getting problems. Is there a way to not let the method post confuse